# CSS text overflow an edge of the redactor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, less

I have redactor the attached to the `div` tag. When I add another `blockquote` the text overflows out of the edge. I need to keep the text inside the red frame I mentioned in the picture no matter how many `blockquote` I add. I don't need a horizontal scrollbar. I need it to fit horizontally and the text should be smashed like in the picture. Please any help or advice.

```
div .redactor {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  padding: 15px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  overflow: initial;
  white-space: normal;
}

<div class="redactor">
<blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">
    <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">
        <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">
            <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">
                <p>Test</p>
            </blockquote>
        </blockquote>
    </blockquote>
</blockquote>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: use position absolute in redactor and outer div give position relative

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to use !important because your code will get messy when it's growing.

For disabling the scrollbar horizontally you can use:`overflow-x:hidden`.
To "smash" your text vertically you have to use:`writing-mode: vertical-lr;text-orientation: upright;`

The easiest way to position your code 2D is [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

See the official docs for both css selectors: [Overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) and [Text-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation).

Take a look at this code, maybe it helps you to understand how it works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=q, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        display: flex;
      }
      .redactor {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: initial;
        white-space: normal;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      div p {
        writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        text-orientation: upright;
        text-align: right;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="redactor">
      <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px">
        <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px">
          <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px">
            <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px">
              <p>Test</p>
            </blockquote>
          </blockquote>
        </blockquote>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```